# Set innerHTML in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there any alternative to JS 'innerHTML' property in CoffeeScript?

In JS, you would end up writing something like:

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = "blah_blah"
```

What is the alternative to do that in CoffeeScript? I have already tried:

```
element = $('element')
element.html "blah_blah"
```

Comment: CoffeeScript simply provides a different syntax to write JS. It doesn't have anything to do with the DOM API. So I guess the answer to *"Is there any alternative to JS 'innerHTML' property in CoffeeScript?"* is *no*, because that's not what CoffeeScript does. The code you posted actually looks like you are using jQuery, but with the wrong selector. Should be `$('#element')`.

Comment: So, you are saying that I need to do same old boring stuff again.. :) Something like:

document.getElementById()...

Comment: See my updated comment. CoffeeScript: A "language" that compiles to JS. jQuery: A JS library around the DOM API. Those are two unrelated and independent things.

Comment: _"I have already tried:"_ ... and what happened when you tried that?

Comment: Looks like its just a bug in your jQuery selector: http://jsfiddle.net/xf3kgkhv/1/

Comment: @FelixKling, I have posted an answer to this. Would that make sense to you in respect of coffee scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an alternative to do that in coffee script.

```
password        = $('#user_password')
message.html "Password Match"
```

I missed '#' selector tag in my question.

Comment: Again, even though you wrote CoffeeScript, the API you are using to change the content is not CoffeScript, it's jQuery. This is how it would like in JS + jQuery: `var password = $('#user_password'); message.html("Password Match");`. All that CoffeScript does is change the syntax a little, it doesn't introduce a new API. Your question is based on a false premise. It should not have been "how to do that in CoffeScript" but "how to use jQuery correctly". Whether you use JS or CS is irrelevant to the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeScript doesn't replace or augment the DOM API. If you want to use some fancy syntax, then check out the examples below. They all do the same thing.

CoffeeScript (without jQuery):

```
document.getElementById('element').innerHTML = 'blah_blah'

(document.getElementById 'element').innerHTML = 'blah_blah'

document
  .getElementById 'element'
  .innerHTML = 'blah_blah'
```

CoffeeScript (with jQuery, note the # in the selector):

```
$('#element').html 'blah_blah'

($ '#element').html 'blah_blah'

$ '#element'
  .html 'blah_blah'
```